# angular2-grid + hammerjs: Fire drag events on press

Tags: events, angular, drag-and-drop, touch, hammer.js

I have an angular 2 web application. I am using angular2-grid for it's drag item features. Sadly, angular2-grid is not touch enabled. Hence, I have integrated HammerJs. I am able to handle angular2-grid drag events and HammerJs press events separately.

Now, I need to allow the items in the grid to be draggable on press. For this I need to fire angular2-grid onDragStart event on HammerJS press event and angular2-grid onDragStop event on HammerJS pressup event. How do I achieve this?

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```html
<div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{'max_cols': 3, 'auto_resize': true}">
        <sticky-note *ngFor="let item of items"
                     [stickyNote]="sNotes" class="grid-item" [(ngGridItem)]='item.config'
                     (onDragStop)="dragged(item)"  (press)="pressed($event, item)" (pressup)="pressedup($event, item)" > </sticky-note>
</div>
```

Can I extract the ngGridItem instance of this item?